# Errors when trying to deploy xamarin application to device (project builds correctly)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, intercom

Hello everyone: I have an old xamarin android app I wanted to update. Changes I've made:

- -Convert old PCL project to .NET standard
- -Migrate dependencies from packages.config to PackageReference
- -Update to the last version of VS so I'm using d8/r8 right now (until now we were using dx)

I've fixed lots and lots of errors until I've finally got a build done.

Now I'm facing a really odd issue: the project compiles correctly, but when I want to deploy to a physical device, then I've got several errors like this(apparently related to my Intercom library binding, but I think this is misleading because the project was working just fine with the same binding and compiled using dx):

```
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/empty_text_subtitle'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/intercom_composer_full_screen_toolbar'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginBottom' with value '@dimen/intercom_composer_activity_margin'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/intercom_composer_tap_to_send'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'fitsSystemWindows' with value '@bool/intercom_composer_fits_system_windows').
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingTop' with value '@dimen/intercom_composer_toolbar_content_offset'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginEnd' with value '@dimen/intercom_composer_activity_margin'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/intercom_composer_circular_ripple'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginRight' with value '@dimen/intercom_composer_activity_margin'). 
Error APT1134: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_height' with value '@dimen/intercom_composer_toolbar_with_status_bar_height')
```

I really appreciate any clue about how to resolve this.

PS: I DO NOT have access to those layouts from the Errors: they belong to the Intercom Java library, which was used to generate the Xamarin binding project

Comment: Hi , have a look at this :https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4194 maybe helpful .

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT : thank you for your suggestion, but in my proguard file I don't have any of the lines mentioned on that issue. In fact, as I said, the project is built correctly, no "java exited with error... blah"  here. The issue happens when I want to deploy to a device only. The deploy is failing, not the build